# Expandable list view layout direction not working in tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, expandablelistview, tablet

I am running an application on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.7 inch screen size. I made a different layouts for different screen sizes. The problem is that the direction of the expandable list view is from right to left and it should be left to right. It works on other devices but not this one.

Here is the code for expandable list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_welcome"
        >
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey"
            android:theme="@style/MenuItems"
            android:textSize="2dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the image with the wrong alignment. The text should be on the left side of the drawer:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who comes across this question, the problem was with the device. Because of its resolution, it was inverted. I ran it on another device with a similar model and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `layoutDirection` and add `alignParentLeft = true`.

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey"
            android:theme="@style/MenuItems"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"

            />
```

Comment: @Pousti: "it's not working" with a sad-face emoticon is not a helpful response. You are presently saying that someone should keep guessing with new ideas until it is fixed. It is much better for you to explain _how_ it is not working, whether you noticed anything that would help, or use the idea for new avenues of research.

Comment: Share your code ? What ever you shared its not helping to give solution to your problem..

Comment: @halfer tell me something useful if you can. Plus yes i tried different direction and layout alignment related tags but nothing works.. The code seems to be working fine on other devices. Even in the studio design panel,the layout alignment changes according to the tags but it does'nt on the device.

Comment: I don't understand for what reason you have added android:layoutDirection="rtl" tag. As I told in my answer, remove this and also share you xml layout for list item.

Comment: It is for direction of the expandable list view.. rtl means right to left.. other attribute of direction is ltr (left to right).. both of them changes the direction of list view items in the design pannel of the studio and on other devices but not on this one

Comment: I know what 'rtl' and 'ltr' is. I mean if you want your text to be align to left of the view why are you adding this tag itself. By default its 'ltr'.

Comment: yes it is. I removed this tag and applied what you said but it didnt changed. Seems like a mystery to me too. Or maybe its a problem with the device